# grep command to extract time in "HR:MIN MST" format from the log file

Tags: awk, grep, extract, text-processing

Here's a sample of a log file format I am creating from my program.

### Sample log file

```
Job execution started 2018-05-16 05:54:08 MST
Starting  job for '2018-05-16' 
Starting  job for '2018-05-16' 
Control table  count is : '33768' 
Processing batch_id: '11548
11568
11598
11611
11637
11662
11688
Completed  job for '2018-05-16' 
Job execution completed 2018-05-16 06:04:59 MST
```

I want to extract only the start time and end time from a log file. Can anyone help me determine how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` like:

```
awk -F'[ :]' '/Job execution (started|completed)/{ print $5 ":" $6, $8}' infile
```

This sets field separator either a *colon or space* and print the fields 5, 6 and 7 from the lines matched with the given patterns `/.../` only.